# C# Call Dictionary<string, string> based on value returned from another Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

Is there a way to dynamically call a related Dictionary<string, string> based on a returned value?

Therefore in the example below, the value shouldBeDictionary1 returned from TestDictionary would return the value Green from Dictionary1 based on the key G passed:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> TestDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "Blah", new List<string>(new[] { "Something", "Dictionary1" })},
    { "Blah, blah", new List<string>(new[] { "Something else", "Dictionary2" }) }        
};

private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "G", "Green"},
    { "A", "Amber"},
    { "R", "Red"}
};

private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "B", "Blue"},
    { "P", "Purple"}
};

private string Test()
{
    var shouldBeSomething = TestDictionary["Blah"][0];

    var shouldBeDictionary1 = TestDictionary["Blah"][1];

    return shouldBeDictionary1["G"] // returned value should be Green

    //MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetMethod(shouldBeDictionary1)
}
```

Attempted to use Reflection in the example above, methodInfo returns null, therefore Invoke cannot be used.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you referring to the other dictionaries by name and not reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, store your references to dictionaries inside its own dictionary:

```
var dictionaryIndex = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>{
  ["Dictionary1"] = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "G", "Green"},
    { "A", "Amber"},
    { "R", "Red"}
  },
  ["Dictionary2"] = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "B", "Blue"},
    { "P", "Purple"}
  }
};

var shouldBeSomething = TestDictionary["Blah"][0];

var shouldBeDictionary1 = TestDictionary["Blah"][1];

return dictionaryIndex[shouldBeDictionary1]["G"] // returned value should be Green
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however my example above is very simplistic, the actual problem could involve over 100 translation dictionaries, spanning multiple methods. Your solution, would invoke chaining 100's of dictionaries per method.

Comment: @iggyweb ok, I can only answer based on the information in your question though...

Comment: BTW you dont have to repeat this, your `dictionaryIndex` can be static

Comment: Thank you @Jamiec, as you have rightly stated creating a `private static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> DictionaryIndex = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` did the trick nicely, thank you.